# CodeIgniter form with GET method is not creating URL with segments

Tags: forms, codeigniter, get

I am using the following form in CI view file :

```
<form name = "transaction_search" action="" method="GET">
    <input name="first" type="text" value="First"/>
    <input name="second" type="text" value="Second"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

But when I hit submit button, it neither changes the URL and the values are not passed to the function.

My config is like :

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']= 'd'; // experimental not currently in use
```

I am okay with the URI segments. The sole purpose is if I search for something, that should be in the URL. How can I make it

EDIT:

Instead of URI segments it is showing query string itself. But I don't want it.

Two things :

1. I am using HMVC extension
2. Using a 3rd party template called AceAdmin and jqgrid along with it.

Comment: try `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;` and check.

Comment: Then also it is not working

Comment: which function? you dont have action attribute.

Comment: from where are you calling this view file?and where you want it to redirect?Since your action is blank how it will redirect?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Provided code works fine for me with freash setup of codeigniter v2.1.4

Comment: It is redirecting the URL for you  ? I am actually working with the HMVC extension. So it is separated in modules.